# Name can be undefined Warning after adding try/except to my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1zG4.png)I wrote code to convert microwave times for different wattages. It's beginner level but it works and even stops the user from inputting letters instead of numbers. However, I get warning messages saying Names can be undefined. Here is the code and any help would be appreciated.

```
while True:
    try:
        time1 = int(input('Enter original time in seconds: '))
        power1 = int(input('Enter original power in watts: '))
        power2 = int(input('Enter new power in watts: '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a number.")
        continue
    else:
        break


def power_conversion(x, y, z):

    return int(x)/int(y)*int(z)


time2 = power_conversion(power1, power2, time1)

print('Cooking time in a '+str(power2)+' watt microwave is:')
print(str(int(time2/60))+':'+(str(int(time2-(60*int(time2/60))))).zfill(2))
```

Comment: Where's the warning message?

Comment: time1, power1 and power2 are not in the same scope as the code using it, they are inside a try which is inside a while. Although you can use them they "could" be null (they won't) as they aren't declared in the same level print is executed

Comment: I added a screenshot with the warnings

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Pita helped me answer this question. This is the new code. I just moved the function to the top and the variable "time2" inside the loop.

```
def power_conversion(x, y, z):

    return int(x)/int(y)*int(z)


while True:
    try:
        time1 = int(input('Enter original time in seconds: '))
        power1 = int(input('Enter original power in watts: '))
        power2 = int(input('Enter new power in watts: '))
        time2 = power_conversion(power1, power2, time1)
    except ValueError:
        print("Please input a number.")
        continue
    else:
        print('Cooking time in a ' + str(power2) + ' watt microwave is:')
        print(str(int(time2 / 60)) + ':' + (str(int(time2 - (60 * int(time2 / 60))))).zfill(2))
        break
```